# Ayuda como conectar un botón con un flujo de datos

Tags: java

Bueno para empezar nuestra profesora de programación nos asigno como tarea conectar una clase con una GUI a una clase con un flujo de datos en un array. la verdad no le entendi mucho ya que no nos enseño como hacerlo, solo nos lo dejo. lo que ella quiere es que por ejemplo al apretar el botón buscar se envíe la matricula la clase  CGrupo y se ejecute el método. Adjunto las clases. Si pudieran ayudar con la forma de "activar" el metodo desde la interfaz o con algun tutorial sobre como hacerlo, lo agredeceria mucho. O si es muy largo el codigo para leerlo me serviria un ejemplo corto de como iniciar el flujo de datos desde un boton y yo hago lo demas.

Clase con la GUI

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CMenuAlumno extends CVentana {
    private JLabel lMatricula, lNombre, lFecha, lPromedio, lTelefono, lEdad, lSemestre, lCarrera, lTurno, lTitulo;
    private JTextField tMatricula, tNombre, tFecha, tPromedio, tTelefono, tEdad, tSemestre, tCarrera, tTurno;
    private JButton bNuevo, bAgregar, bEliminar, bBuscar, bSalir;
    private Panel p1, p2, p3, pg;

    public CMenuAlumno() {
        super("Registro de Alumnos", -10, 200, 800, 400, false);

        p1 = new Panel();
        p2 = new Panel();
        p3 = new Panel();
        pg = new Panel();
        lTitulo = new JLabel(" Datos del Alumno");
        lTitulo.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lTitulo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        p1.add(lTitulo);
        lMatricula = new JLabel("Matricula:", JLabel.CENTER);
        lMatricula.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lNombre = new JLabel("Nombre:");
        lNombre.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lPromedio = new JLabel("Promedio:");
        lPromedio.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lTelefono = new JLabel("Telefono:");
        lTelefono.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lEdad = new JLabel("Edad:");
        lEdad.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lFecha = new JLabel("Fecha:");
        lFecha.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lSemestre = new JLabel("Semestre:");
        lSemestre.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lCarrera = new JLabel("Carrera:");
        lCarrera.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lTurno = new JLabel("Turno:");
        lTurno.setFont(new Font("Bradley HandITC", Font.BOLD, 18));
        tMatricula = new JTextField("", 20);
        tNombre = new JTextField("", 20);
        tPromedio = new JTextField("", 20);
        tTelefono = new JTextField("", 20);
        tEdad = new JTextField("", 20);
        tFecha = new JTextField("", 20);
        tSemestre = new JTextField("", 20);
        tCarrera = new JTextField("", 20);
        tTurno = new JTextField("", 20);
        p2.add(lMatricula);
        p2.add(tMatricula);
        p2.add(lNombre);
        p2.add(tNombre);
        p2.add(lPromedio);
        p2.add(tPromedio);
        p2.add(lTelefono);
        p2.add(tTelefono);
        p2.add(lEdad);
        p2.add(tEdad);
        p2.add(lFecha);
        p2.add(tFecha);
        p2.add(lSemestre);
        p2.add(tSemestre);
        p2.add(lCarrera);
        p2.add(tCarrera);
        p2.add(lTurno);
        p2.add(tTurno);
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2));
        bNuevo = new JButton("Nuevo");
        bNuevo.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        bNuevo.addActionListener(new MiAccionNuevo());
        bAgregar = new JButton("Agregar");
        bAgregar.addActionListener(new Agregar());
        bAgregar.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        bEliminar = new JButton("Eliminar");
        bEliminar.addActionListener(new AccionEliminar());
        bEliminar.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        bBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
        bBuscar.addActionListener(new AccionBuscar());
        bBuscar.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        bSalir = new JButton("Salir");
        bSalir.addActionListener(new Salir());
        bSalir.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        p3.add(bNuevo);
        p3.add(bAgregar);
        p3.add(bEliminar);
        p3.add(bBuscar);
        p3.add(bSalir);
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 2, 2));
        pg.add(p1);
        pg.add(p2);
        pg.add(p3);
        pg.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 120, 10));
        this.add(pg);
        pack();
        doLayout();
    }

    public class MiAccionNuevo implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pEvento) {



        }
    }

    public class Salir implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pEvento) {
            int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea Salir", "Salir", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                CVentanaEscuela ventana=new CVentanaEscuela();
                ventana.setVisible(true);
                ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                ventana.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }

        }
    }

    public class Agregar implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public class AccionBuscar implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        }
    }

    public class AccionEliminar implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        }
    }

public static void main (String[] args) {

        CMenuAlumno ventana1=new CMenuAlumno();
        ventana1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Clase 1

```
// Clase con la Estructura del registro de datos.
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CAlumnos implements Serializable
{
    private short matricula;
    private short semestre;
    private String nombre, carrera, turno;
    private double promedio;

    public CAlumnos() {
        matricula=0;
        semestre=0;
        nombre="";
        carrera="";
        turno="";
    }

    public CAlumnos (short mat, String nom, short sem, String car,
            String tur, double prom) { 
        setMatricula( mat);
        setNombre(nom);
        setSemestre( sem);
        setCarrera (car);
        setTurno( tur);
        setPromedio(prom);
    }

    public void setMatricula(short mat) { 
        matricula = mat;
    }

    public short getMatricula() { 
        return (matricula);
    }

    public void setPromedio (double prom) {     
        promedio=prom;
    }

    public double getPromedio() { 
        return (promedio);
    }

    public void setNombre(String nom) { 
        nombre = nom;
    }

    public String getNombre() { 
        return (nombre);
    }

    public void setSemestre(short sem) { 
        semestre = sem;
    }

    public short getSemestre() { 
        return (semestre);
    }

    public void setCarrera(String car) { 
        carrera = car;
    }

    public String getCarrera() { 
        return (carrera);
    }

    public void setTurno(String tur) { 
        turno = tur;
    }

    public String getTurno() { 
        return (turno);
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Matricula:"+matricula+"\n"+
                        "Nombre: "+nombre+"\n"+
                        "semestre: "+semestre+"\n"+
                        "Carrera: "+carrera+"\n"+
                        "Turno: "+turno+"\n"+
                        "Promedio: "+promedio+"\n"
                );
    }

}
```

Clase 2

```
/* Clase Grupo. Objeto que representa un array de Alumno */
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CGrupo implements Serializable
{
    private CAlumnos[ ] arrAlumnos;
    private int nElementos;

    public CGrupo() { // Crea el array 

        nElementos = 0;
        arrAlumnos = inicializar(nElementos);

    }

    private CAlumnos[] inicializar(int nElementos) {

        try
        { return (new CAlumnos[nElementos]);
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        return (arrAlumnos);
        }

    }

    public CAlumnos elemento( int i ) {

        if (i >= 0 && i < nElementos)
        return (arrAlumnos[i]);

        else { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No hay elementos en esa posicion");
            return (null);
        }

    }

    public int longitud() { 

        return (arrAlumnos.length);

    }

    public void agregar(short pMatricula, String pNombre, short
            pSemestre, String pCarrera, String pTurno, double calif) { 

        CAlumnos unAlumno=new CAlumnos(pMatricula, pNombre, pSemestre, pCarrera, pTurno, calif);
        CAlumnos[] copiaDeLista;
        //el array crece conforme se le van aadiendo nuevos elementos
        copiaDeLista = arrAlumnos;
        nElementos = copiaDeLista.length;
        arrAlumnos = inicializar(nElementos + 1);
        for ( int i = 0; i < nElementos; i++ )
        arrAlumnos[i] = copiaDeLista[i];
        arrAlumnos[nElementos] = unAlumno;
        nElementos++;

    }

    public boolean eliminar(short mat) {
        CAlumnos[] copiaDeLista;
        int posi = buscar(mat);
        if (posi != -1)
        { // el array disminuye cuando se eliminan elementos
            arrAlumnos[posi] = null;
            copiaDeLista = arrAlumnos;
            if (copiaDeLista.length != 0)
            { int k = 0;
            nElementos = copiaDeLista.length;
            arrAlumnos = inicializar(nElementos - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < nElementos; i++)
                if (copiaDeLista[i] != null)
                    arrAlumnos[k++] = copiaDeLista[i];
            nElementos--;
            return (true);
            }
        }
        return (false);
    }
    public int buscar(short mat)
    {
        int posi = 0;
        if (posi < nElementos)
            for (int i = posi; i <= nElementos; i++)
            {
                if ( arrAlumnos[i].getMatricula()== mat)
                {
                    return( i);
                }
            }
        return (-1);
    }
}
```

Clase 3

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CArchAlumnos
{
    public CGrupo lista = null;
    // Apuntador al inicio de los datos. Si la lista sufre cambios se escribe en el disco
    public boolean cambios;
    public CArchAlumnos()
    {
        leer();
        operaciones();
        escribir();
    }
    public void leer()
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        //definiendo el flujo de lectura para un archivo existente
        try
        { /* Creacin considera dos casos si el archivo existe
previamente o no */
            File fichero = new File("ArchAlumnos.txt");
            if (!fichero.exists())
            { lista = new CGrupo();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Nuevo archivo");
            }
            else
            { ois = new ObjectInputStream(new
                    FileInputStream("ArchAlumnos.txt"));
            lista = (CGrupo)ois.readObject();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Archivo existente");
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: " +
                e.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: " +
                e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            { if (ois != null)
                ois.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {}
        }
    }
    public void escribir()
    { ObjectOutputStream ous = null;
    //si hubo cambios los escribe en el archivo
    try
    { if (cambios)
    { ous = new ObjectOutputStream(new
            FileOutputStream("ArchAlumnos.txt"));
    ous.writeObject(lista);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se guardaron correctamente los datos.");
    }
    lista = null;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: " +
            e.toString());
    }
    finally
    { try
    { if (ous != null)
        ous.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {}
    }
    }
    public void operaciones()
    { short opcion = 0;
    int posi = -1;
    short matricula = 0;
    short semestre = 0;
    String nombre, carrera, turno;
    double promedio=0.0;
    boolean eliminado = false;
    boolean error;
    // Mantenimiento
    try
    { do
    {
        opcion=
                Short.parseShort (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "MENU de movimientos para el archivo de alumnos\n" +
                                "1. Agregar un registro.\n"+
                                "2. Eliminar un registro.\n"+
                                "3. Consultar un registro.\n"+
                                "4. Terminar.\n\n"+
                        "Elija una opción: "));
        switch (opcion)
        { // Se supone que no se introducen matriculas repetidas
        case 1:
            // se trata la excepcin para que vuelva a pedir el dato
            // en el caso de que se introduzca un valor no numrico
            do
            { error = false;
            try
            {
                matricula =
                        Short.parseShort (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Matrícula:"));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Valor no válido(Es necesario un dato numérico)");
                error = true;
            }
            }while (error);
            nombre =
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Nombre: ");
            do
            { error = false;
            try
            {
                semestre =
                        Short.parseShort (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Semestre: "));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Valor no válido(Es necesario un dato numérico)");
                error = true;
            }
            }while (error);
            carrera =
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Carrera: ");
            turno =
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Turno: ");
            do
            { error = false;
            try
            {
                promedio =
                        Double.parseDouble (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Promedio: "));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Valor no válido(Es necesario un dato numérico)");
                error = true;
            }
            }while (error);
            lista.agregar(matricula, nombre,
                    semestre,
                    carrera, turno, promedio);
            cambios = true;
            break;
        case 2: // Eliminar un registro
            do
            { error = false;
            try
            {
                matricula =
                        Short.parseShort (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Matrícula que desea borrar: "));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Valor no válido (Es necesario un dato numérico)");
                error = true;
            }
            }while (error);
            eliminado =
                    lista.eliminar(matricula);
            if (eliminado)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro eliminado");
                cambios = true;
            }
            else
                if (lista.longitud() != 0)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se encuentra el Alumno");
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Archivo vacío");
            break;
        case 3: // consultar un registro
            do
            { error = false;
            try
            {
                matricula =
                        Short.parseShort (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                "Introduzca la matrícula del alumno que desea consultar "));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Valor no válido (Es necesario un dato numérico)");
                error = true;
            }
            }while (error);
            posi = lista.buscar(matricula);
            if (posi == -1)
                if (lista.longitud() != 0)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro no encontrado");
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Archivo vacío");
            else
                lista.elemento(posi).mostrar();
            break;
        case 4:
        }
    }while(opcion != 4);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ne)
    { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Valor no válido (Es necesario un dato numérico)");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes que añadir a tu botón el evento click y dentro de ese crear las clases que desees y llamar a los métodos que necesites. Ese evento pasa por agregar un Listener al botón y luego un actionPerformed

```
jBtnSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
      //programas lo que necesitas
    }});
```